# Difficulties employing a line integral of a half circle.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, physics, electromagnetism

I need to use the following equation (Bio-Savart) of a wire carrying a current, where $d\vec l$ is an infinitesimal piece of wire carrying the charge (the thicker line, half circle)

[image]:

$$d\vec B=\frac{\mu_0I\left(d\vec l \times \vec r\right)}{4\pi (|\vec r|^3)}$$

Where $\left(d\vec l \times \vec r\right)$ is the cross product of $\vec r$ and $d\vec l$.

Now $\vec r=r\sin\theta \hat x +r\cos\theta\hat y $ since we're going clock-wise, but what would I use as $d\vec l$?

Comment: The latex code for the crossproduct is \times

Comment: @Lovsovs thanks, looks much better now

Comment: @RonaldB : And another MathJax-code criticism: Standard notation is $r\sin\theta\hat x$, not $r sin \theta\hat x.$  I changed it. $\qquad$

Comment: I don't quite understand the two sines in your expression for $\vec{r}$ - are you sure it is supposed to be so? Also, are you trying to calculate the B-field at the origin, so $\vec{r}$ points from the wire to the origin? (I can't quite remember the convention for the directional vector, but please specify what $\vec{r}$ is.)

Comment: @Lovsovs whoops meant to be rsin in direction ofx, and rcos in directio of y

Comment: @Lovsovs if I recall correctly it's just the parameterization of a circle opening downwards

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the case, since $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{r}$ then would be parallel and the cross product would be zero - I also remember it differently when I took EM, but I do also remember that you had to be very careful not to mess up that with $\vec{r}$. Look up what $\vec{r}$ is in your textbook - I think that should solve (much of) the issue.

Comment: @kobe That's what I was thinking too. Another issue I have is a $\hat z $component is throw in in the solution manual causing confusion. Not sure where it came from.

Comment: @RonaldB that comes from taking the cross product of $d\vec{l}$ and $\vec{r}$.

Comment: No the actual $d\vec r$ has a z component.

Comment: @RonaldB $d\vec{l}$ cannot have a $\hat{z}$-component because $d\vec{l}/d\theta$ lies in the plane of $xy$-plane.

Comment: @kobe looking at it even closer, it seems as if it's $\vec r$ has a z component since it's looking for the force on a ring at a height of z above the origins. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RonaldB well that makes the difference! Did you miss that you're seeking to find $\vec{B}(0,0,z)$ and not $\vec{B}(0,0,0)$?

Comment: Yes! I didn't think it would affect the solution, but apparently it does quite a bit!

Comment: @kobe just wanted to say thank you for bearing with me and helping me understand the question better

Comment: @RonaldB sure, no problem!